# how to wait for model initialize before starting view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am making a basic trello clone. Except instead of signing in, projects have a slug(i.e. 'www.example.com/1d754b6c')

If a user visits the root, a new slug is created on the back end. The user is then routed to www..com/1d754b6c, which sends another ajax call to get the projects ID. A view is then started. However my view is getting started before the slug -> ID ajax call is finished. Whats the best way to fix this? (I currently have a setTimeout as a temporary patch, I know that is not a good way to accomplish this)

router.js

```
Buckets.Routers.PageRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'newProject',
        ':token': 'displayProject'
    },
    newProject: function () {
        new Buckets.Models.Project({});
    },
    displayProject: function (token) {
        var that = this;
        var project = new Buckets.Models.Project({token: token});
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            new Buckets.Views.showProject({
                            model: project
                        });
        }, 500);

    }
});
```

project.js

```
Buckets.Models.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return Buckets.BASE_URL + '/api/projects/' + (this.id)
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        var that = this;
        if (options && options.token) {
            that.token = options.token
            $.ajax({
                url: Buckets.BASE_URL + '/' + that.token,
                dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data, status ){
                        that.id = data;
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                    url: Buckets.BASE_URL + '/api/projects/new', 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data, status ){
                        that.token = data.token;
                        that.id = data.id;
                        Buckets.Routers.router.navigate('/' + that.token, true);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });
        }
        return this;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Backbone.Model.sync`. `.sync()` returns a Promise so you can take full advantage of the Deffered/Promises standard.

When I want to pass variable urls to the fetch I override the `model.fetch()`. For your implemenation I'd first scrap the `$.ajax` in `initialize()` and override `fetch` like this

```
Buckets.Models.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
  fetch: function(options) {
      var that = this;
      if (options && options.token) {
        this.url = Buckets.BASE_URL + '/' + that.token;
      else
        this.url = Buckets.BASE_URL + '/api/projects/new';

      return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

`.fetch()` eventually returns the result of `sync()` which is a Promise. That means that in your `Router` you'd do this:

```
displayProject: function (token) {
  var that = this;
  var project = new Buckets.Models.Project();
  $.when(project.fetch({token: token})
  // deffered.done() replaces the success callback in your $.ajax
  .done(function() {
    project.id = data;
    new Buckets.Views.showProject({ model: project });
  })
  // deffered.fail() replaces the error callback in your $.ajax
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(jqXHR);
 });
}
```

And for completeness, you'd reweite `newProject()` similarly,

```
newProject: function () {
  var project = new Buckets.Models.Project();
  $.when(project.fetch({token: token})
  .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    project.token = data.token;
    project.id = data.id;
    new Buckets.Views.showProject({ model: project });
  })
  .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
  });
}
```

Try it out. I started using this method of fetching when it was recommended to me by a major contributor to `MarionetteJS`, one of the premier opinionated Backbone frameworks. This method is easy to maintain and very responsive.